# How to implement Website security based on client hardware or other solution?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, activex, security

I have two websites (one asp classic and the other asp.net) which we would like to implement some kind of security based on the client's hardware.  We want something other than a password which could be shared.  The purpose is to be sure access to information on the websites is not shared.

We were contrmplating storing hardware info in our database and validating against that upun website entry.

I have been looking into ActiveX (it would be acceptable to limit our users to IE), although we do have users who would like to use I-Phones.  I have done no ActiveX development myself but have found a few articles on the web about ActiveX but that whole approach looks complicated.  And also there seems to be a 64bit issue making it even more difficult.

So, I wonder if anybody has any advice as to what the best options might be for securing the website access in a way that would prevent sharing?

I wonder if client side certificate authorization would help?  I have not looked into these yet so will research those.

Thank you for any input.

Jim

Comment: Why would it be acceptable to limit your users to IE, **especially** since some of them want to use iPhones?  If the same user can connect to both websites by *any* means, how can you possibly prevent that person from sharing information?

Comment: If there is a solution other than ActiveX, that would be better.  We would be ok restricting them to IE if we have no other means.  We cannot prevent a user from sharing via e-mail or the like.  What we are after is making sure each user doesn't allow another person access to the actual sites by sharing passwords.  Thank you

Comment: maybe I didn't get your point, but sharing a workstation among multiple users on client-side is so common.

Comment: What you're trying to do is almost certainly going to be impossible, strictly speaking. Ask yourself this: what other established sites on the net have you seen that do anything like what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you on both points, I have never seen a website do this, and yes, this seems very problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for really high security, you can perhaps use an [RSA SecurID](http://www.rsa.com/node.aspx?id=1156).

I have a website which I connect to via a little dongle which generates a random key every 60 seconds, combined with a 4 digit pin of my choice.

Sharing it between users could still be possible, but less likely since the key changes all the time. They would need to communicate in person or via phone/chat to share the key..

Comment: Yes, I use those for a couple clients of mine.  That won't work for this application because it would be too restrictive for our users. One of the websites is a forum where users auto-sign in with cookies on email links.  That is why we were wanting to validate against the users hardware.  The user would not need to do anything additional to gain access.  Thanks for the idea however!

Comment: Well in that case, I'd say it's impossible without ActiveX.

Comment: I am working on an ActiveX solution.  I have a long ways to go yet.  I wanted to see if there were any other options first!  Thanks.

Comment: Hummm, anybody know if client side certificate authorization would help?  I will research those, I am not familiar with those yet.